# Show/Hide Div, of divers DIV's

Tags: javascript, html, hide, show

I'm new to this site.

Javascript is not much, but I found a code to show and hide divs.

This is what I have for now, when clicking on Details1 also shown Details2

jsfiddle.net/qU3TG/3/

How I can do to make the effect only to the current item?

example:
If I have the options Details 1 Details 2, 3 ..... Details DetailsN, clicking on Details # shows only the div that belongs.

The effect Show / Hide, applies to everyone, not just one. I would like to help me with this code or wish I could recommend another code

I have almost one day trying to fix this problem but I couldn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your jsFiddle, I've renamed the links inside hidden blocks:

```
<a href="#" class="hide">hide</a>
```

then updated the jQuery code:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/earthdesigner/qU3TG/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this as in your `jQuery` part:

```
$('.slidingDiv .hide').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().slideToggle();
});
```

This will cause the parent `div` which contains the hide anchor to toggle. I hope this is what you needed